# using Java arraylist for storing data from scan from file

Tags: java

I am new to java, but not coding. I am trying to figure out java because it's part of my class this term and I am having a really hard problem grasping the idea of it and implementing things in java.

my problem Is that I am not sure if I am correctly using the arraylist to grab data from the scan of the file and input it into a arraylist to sort and print at a later time. I am just having issues picking up on java any help would be great since I am new to java.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
public class MissionCount
{
    private static  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    // returns an InputStream that gets data from the named file
    private static InputStream getFileInputStream(String fileName) throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {       // no file with this name exists
            inputStream = null;
            throw new Exception("unable to open the file -- " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return inputStream;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("USage: MissionCount <datafile>");
            //System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            System.out.printf("CS261 - MissionCount - Chad Dreher%n%n");
            int crewcount = 0;
            int misscount = 0;
            InputStream log = getFileInputStream(args[0]);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(log);
            sc.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(",|\n"));

            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                String crewMember = sc.next();
                list.add(crewMember);
                String mission = sc.next();
                list.add(mission);
             }
             sc.close();
             // Add code to print the report here
         }catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InputStream log = getFileInputStream(args[0]);
```

Change that line to as follows :-

```
File log = new File(args[0])
```

that should work!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I have six minutes until I can checked answer gamer john.